# Can somebody help me understand this regex pattern?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have some knowledge of MySQL regexp syntax but I am not proficient. I was looking for a way to construct a pattern that selects all names from a mysql table that contain strange characters due to international input such as spanish names that have the symbol on top of the n.

I came upon this following pattern which I tried and it worked.

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9@:. \'\-`,\&]
```

The query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders_table
WHERE customers_name REGEXP  '[^a-zA-Z0-9@:. \'\-`,\&]'
```

However I would like to understand how this pattern was constructed and what each part means.

Comment: [Here](https://regex101.com/r/zpw6ju/1) you go.

Comment: This is called a **negated character class**: every character of the class must **not** be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that anything between [...] is a character class, which matches any single character that's in the set between the [ and ].

Adding the ^ to the start of the list of characters means (as noted above) it's negated, which means it matches any character NOT in the set. Putting a ^ anywhere but the start of the [ ... ]  means it's just a regular ^ character to match, and in no case does ^ inside a character class mean a start-of-line anchor.

Ranges work, such as a-z, and if you want a literal dash in the set, you either put it first (possibly after the ^), or quote it with \

Edit: the other special characters - @ : etc. - are not special in this context, they just match as regular characters.

Comment: To answer the SQL question, it looks like it's searching for any customer names that contains things **other than** what's in the list, so if a customer name had (say) a dollar sign, it would match.

Answer (score 0):

[a-zA-Z0-9@:. \'-`,\&] - Let us consider all the important parts of this pattern.

`[]` -  denotes a character class which matches any single character within [].

`[a-zA-Z0-9]` -- One character (lowercase or uppercase) that is in the range of a-z,A-Z OR 0-9.

All other characters which are present within the `[]` match for a particular single character.
single quotes `"'"`  and ampersand `&` are escaped by `"\"` because in sql, they are used for specific purposes.

To match a pattern which has a character **other than** any of these symbols within `[]`, we use a negation `"^"` at the beginning.

Thus, as you have told ,your pattern selects all names from a mysql table that contain other strange characters.